# .NET testing, best way for Test Team to save environment for faster work by Dev Team to fix bugs

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

We have a .NET application that has grown over time and now has multiple bugs.  Is there anyway for the Test Team to aid in the data provided to the Dev Team to fix the bugs?  Right now, they try to repro the problem and write out the steps manually.  Then the Dev Team has to try and recreate the steps and trace through the code.  Is there some way for the Test Team to save all the work they have done and then pass it on to the Dev Team to then start the debugging from that point?

We are using VS 2010.

We have apps in ASP.NET, WinForms, and WCF Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at **IntelliTrace**? Here is the Microsoft [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264954.aspx) I think that is what you are looking for. Scenario: Test team does test throw error, attaches intellitrace to work item, passes the work item on to dev team. Dev team is able to step through the code and "reproduce" the error.